# Executing IPython notebooks in a make file / from the command line

Tags: python, makefile, jupyter-notebook

I am wondering if there is a way to run all cells of an IPython notebook from the command line (there probably is)?

The purpose of this would be to put this command into a `make` file, e.g., for a reproducible data analysis pipeline. Of course, it could be all converted to python scripts, however, if there is a way to make it work with the IPython notebook, it would be even better.

make file example:

```
some_data.zip:
    curl -o some_data.zip 'http://some_address.zip'

some_data.csv: some_data.zip
    unzip some_data.zip
    python preprocessing.py some_data.dat

grpahic.png: some_data.csv
    # run ipython notebook somehow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purposes, how about the following:

First:

```
ipython nbconvert --to=python [YOUR_NOTEBOOK].ipynb
```

Then:

```
python [YOUR_NOTEBOOK].py
```

What this will do from your make file will convert `.ipynb` to `.py`, then run your `.py`

Comment: Just realize this is a 3-year old question and I never updated it. Yeah, that's a good approach and how I was doing it in the mean time, thanks :)